# Retweet using STTwitter API

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter-feed, sttwitter

I have tried to add the retweet concept in my application using STTwitter API with following method after user authentication:

```
[twitter postStatusRetweetWithID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"691544087921606656"] successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {
       NSLog(@"status..%@",status);
   } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"error..%@",error);
   }];
```

But it is showing following error:

> Error Domain=**STTwitterTwitterErrorDomain** **Code=220** "Your
>   credentials do not allow access to this resource."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7b170ca0 {Error Domain=STHTTPRequest
>   Code=403 "HTTP Status 403: Forbidden"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=HTTP Status 403: Forbidden}},
>   NSLocalizedDescription=**Your credentials do not allow access to this
>   resource.**}

If anyone has experienced with the STTwitter API. Suggest me some idea to get rid from this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) This code works for me, I could retweet this tweet with my test account https://twitter.com/nst022 2) I cannot spot any error in your code, although you don't need -[NSString stringWithFormat:] you can simply use @"691544087921606656" 3) Maybe there's something wrong with your credentials. What's the result of -[STTwitterAPI verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock:errorBlock:]?